# How do I pass a angularjs variable into html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In controller:

```
$scope.height = "height:100px;";
$scope.color = "red"
```

In HTML:

```
<div class="capsule" ng-style="{'height': height; 'background': color}"></div>
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: that in theory should work.

Comment: can you show us that it doesn't work?

Comment: I am getting the feeling your approach if off, if your model contains your CSS.

Comment: simple typo, you have `;` where you should have `,`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a semi colon ';' in between the style, ng-style expects an object (comma separated). The below code should work -

```
<div class="capsule" ng-style="{'height': height, 'background': color}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to use the `ng-style` directive, which takes an object that describes styles names and their values, like so:

`<div class="capsule"  ng-style="{'height': height}"></div>`

Comment: Thanks. How about this one?   <div class="capsule" ng-style="{'height': height; 'background': color}"></div>

Comment: That should work as well.

Comment: It will not work, it expect an object which is comma separated. Please see my answer

Comment: Oh, you're right -- I did not catch their typo.